# How do I modify rpm spec file to install a tarball to specific directory?

Tags: rpm, rpm-spec

I want to install gstatus to /usr/local/gstatus/gstatus-0.66. The original tarball install it to <current_path>/gstatus-0.66. How do I modify the spec to make it install to the right place?
Original spec:

```
Name:           gstatus
Version:        0.66
Release:        1%{?dist}
...
Source0:        %{name}-%{version}.tar.gz
BuildRoot:      %(mktemp -ud %{_tmppath}/%{name}-%{version}-%{release}-XXXXXX)
...
%prep
%setup -q -n %{name}
...
%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
%{__python} setup.py install --skip-build --root %{buildroot} --install-scripts %{_bindir}
mkdir -p %{buildroot}%{_mandir}/man8
install -m 0644 gstatus.8 %{buildroot}%{_mandir}/man8/
gzip %{buildroot}%{_mandir}/man8/gstatus.8
...
```

/usr/local does exist, but I need to create /usr/local/gstatus.
Can I modify %install section to:

```
%install
rm -rf %{buildroot}
mkdir /usr/local/gstatus
%{__python} setup.py install --skip-build --root /usr/local/gstatus/%{buildroot} --install-scripts %{_bindir}
mkdir -p /usr/local/gstatus/%{buildroot}%{_mandir}/man8
install -m 0644 gstatus.8 /usr/local/gstatus/%{buildroot}%{_mandir}/man8/
gzip /usr/local/gstatus/%{buildroot}%{_mandir}/man8/gstatus.8
...
```

Comment: Installing things to `/usr/local` is against many packaging guidelines. Ideally install it `/usr/bin/` if it is a binary, and if other same-name binary exists, use a version suffix of some kind, etc. Other (but less preferrable) option is installing to `/opt/<program>/bin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Inside the `%install` section you need to put everything under `%{buildroot}`. You probably should do something like:

```
%install
mkdir -p %{buildroot}/usr/local/gstatus/
--root %{buildroot}/usr/local/gstatus/

%files
/usr/local/gstatus/
```

A few notes:

- yes you need to create all directories under `%{buildroot}` (/usr etc), but you should only package the directories that belong to you. The packaging happens in `%files`
- under `%files` specifying a directory is recursive by default. By specifying `/usr/local/gstatus/` here, the directory `gstatus` is packaged recursively.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris!! That a very good explanation. I'll edit it and rebuild again. (I use "mkrpm localbuild")